# openvpn: can't manage to control client-to-client connections with iptables

Tags: iptables, openvpn, docker, centos7

I tried this article: http://backreference.org/2010/05/02/controlling-client-to-client-connections-in-openvpn/ but had no luck.

I'm new to iptables. Can you please have a look at my configuration?

Docker container (I'm using this one: https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn) is run in **host** network mode

I'm using Centos7 with `firewalld` disabled and `iptables` installed and enabled.

ip_forward is enabled.

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

`redirect-gateway def1` is turned off as I don't need to route internet traffic through vpn server.

Here are initial iptables rules.

```
[root]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Every client has a configuration file in `ccd` directory with a static IP. 
Here's how I do it for one of clients `ifconfig-push 10.8.0.102 10.8.0.1`

In my `openvpn.conf` I have `client-to-client` directive disabled.

I have `tun0` iface and `10.8.0.0/24` network.

First off, I allow already established connections:
`iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Then I set forward rules for 2 clients can reach each other:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.10 -d 10.8.0.102 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.102 -d 10.8.0.10 -j ACCEPT
```

After all it doesn't work. When I perform `ping 10.8.0.102` from my MAC (which has ip 10.8.0.10) I get:

```
➜  ~ ping 10.8.0.102
PING 10.8.0.102 (10.8.0.102): 56 data bytes
36 bytes from gwr-vl-201.**** (***.**.**.133): Communication prohibited by filter
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 29e3   0 0000  3d  01 8749 192.168.1.103  10.8.0.102
```

192.168.1.103 - is my LAN address

Here's my route table on a mac:

```
➜  ~ netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           65        0     en0
10.8.0.1           10.8.0.10          UH              0        0   utun1
46.101.242.41/32   192.168.1.1        UGSc            0        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             24     2286     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.1          link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.1.1/32     link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
192.168.1.1        84:16:f9:c5:c4:da  UHLWIir        63       26     en0   1043
192.168.1.103/32   link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
224.0.0/4          link#4             UmCS            1        0     en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
```

And my route table on the server:

```
[]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         217.182.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-44c0269fbf91
217.**.**.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
217.**.**.**1  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give the result of the command route -n (used to display the route table ?). Also, did you try disabling firewall (iptables -F) to see if ping is work without any filter?

Comment: Aaah! I finally got it to work! All I needed is to `add push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"` to the server config!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work!

All I had to do is add `push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"` to the server config.

After that I can create arbitrary iptables forward rules (as I did in the post above) and then add

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

to deny everything else.